# See files listed in stash without applying it (not diff).

Tags: git, terminal

I don't want to see the diff, I just want to see a nice list of files in a stash.  I'm having trouble finding that.  I am not seeing it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755453/git-drop-file-in-a-stash-without-applying-it), and I'm not seeing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725729/see-whats-in-a-stash-without-applying-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass [`--name-only`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---name-only) to [`git stash show`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-showltstashgt) to show the most recent stash:

```
git stash show --name-only
```

To show stashes other than the most recent, pass `stash@{N}` where `N` is the stash number desired (`0` being the most recent, also `git stash list` to list all stashes), e.g.:

```
git stash show --name-only stash@{0}
```

Many arguments that `git diff` accepts should be accepted by `git stash show`; sadly this isn’t very obvious, and `--name-only` isn’t documented under `man git-stash`.

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
git diff --name-only stash@{0}^ stash@{0}
```

This will show the files in `stash@{0}`.